# LINQ query improvement

Tags: c#, .net

I have been banging my head on the wall from past two days but I am unable to improve the timing of the following LINQ.

```
from obj in list
from obj1 in list1
where (obj1.ClassesName.Contains(obj.ClassName) && obj1.Count> 0)
select new { result = obj1.ClassName})
```

I need to search for **obj.classname** in **obj1.classesname** list. Once found in the classesname list I need to return the obj1 classname.

I have 5 thousand objects in list.

The above query takes more than 30 seconds to run. I need to cut this time time down under 5 seconds.

I am confused and every help will count.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using normal loops instead? I've had LINQ queries run slow and I've just replaced them with normal constructs and they run faster sometimes.

Comment: should this just return 1 result? or lots of results?

Comment: I think providing some sample data and expected output would help, since it's not clear what the type of 'ClassesName' is (string? string array?) and if the Contains is meant as a substring or collection operation.  If collection, does it need to be case-insensitive?  What does obj1.Count refer to?

Comment: I have used normal loops it took more than 2 minutes. It was a disaster.

Comment: Can you please post the classes obj and obj1 i think part of your problem as is appears is that your doing 250000 string.contains operations, this is never going to be fast

Comment: Hi James,Thanks for your response. The ClassesName is a List<string>. And Contains is substring operation.

Comment: @user1232020: `obj1.ClassesName` is a `List<string>` ? Then Contains is not substring matching its looking for an item in the collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious improvement is to move the `Count > 0`  condition for `list1` out, so you don't have to consider those items at all:

```
from obj in list
from obj1 in list1.Where(x=> x.Count >0)
where (obj1.ClassesName.Contains(obj.ClassName))
select new { result = obj1.ClassName})
```

Since `ClassesName` is a `List<string>` you can do some pre-processing as well to use a `Hashtable<string>` instead. That will make the lookup O(1) instead of O(n), with n the number of items in list1.

Answer (score 0):

```
(from obj1 in list1
where (obj1.Count > 0) && System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(from obj in list where obj1.ClassesName.Contains(obj.ClassName) select obj)
select new { result = obj1.ClassName});
```

This will stop looking when it finds a match, thats what Any does, this would reduce the number of records your looking through, but maybe i don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: why is that faster?  (just curious).

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable.Any stops when it finds a result

Comment: Why call it as a static method instead of extension method?  Seems weird IMHO :)

Comment: im sure that doesn't matter its just how i started doing it when i was learning linq, call it a quirk, coming from T/SQL it mimics the way an inline select works so i guess its just more readable to me.